# Pressure mapping a Brooks saddle

Tags: bike-fit, saddle, leather

As part of a bike fit I had done recently I had my well broken in Brooks Team Pro Classic pressure mapped (via the [GebioMized](http://gebiomized.de/?lang=en) system). (A pressure mapping creates a 2-dimensional mapping of the pressure exhibited across the saddle - useful for modifying fit). The results were quite astounding; an incredibly low pressure mapping, so low we were mostly at the limit of what could be detected by the system.

It was suggested doing some more testing and writing it up for publication (we had a long discussion of all the years of trial and errors I have done with Brooks) - which I am interested in doing.

*My questions pertains to existing literature, some of which is not easily searchable through general internet searches.*

### Questions

1. **Are there any published pressure mappings of leather saddles such as Brooks?**
2. **Is there any canonical sources out there for breaking in and setting up a leather saddle?**

   - Most discussions appear to be opinion based short articles, forum discussions and other largely non-citable dialog.
   - Most also discuss a general trial-and-error approach with some anecdotal accounts, nothing measurable and repeatable.
   - As always Sheldon Brown has a [nice summary](http://sheldonbrown.com/leather.html), but I wouldn't consider it an in-depth guide.

Comment: I bought a Brooks seat so I wouldn't have to worry about this.

Comment: Right now most accounts are anecdotal (such as your answer). The point of the question is to see any measurable and repeatable results have been published.

Comment: While GebioMized is an excellent system for this purpose, I'm not sure this question is a good fit for the Bicycles.SE site. It requires specialized knowledge, and if answered  will not benefit anyone on the site other than the OP. That said, I do think the research itself would be useful.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the required knowledge to answer it is very specific, and not likely available to anyone outside of the Brooks or GebioMized companies. I would suggest directing questions about the data availability to Michael Fuhrmeister at GebioMized. The company was started as a research division of the Sports University at Freiburg in Germany, so I'm sure they would be interested in furthering the research in this matter. It also has no long term benefit as an answer for future users of this site, in my opinion.

Comment: @zenbike - Saddles and bike fit are off-topic?  This topic would be of interest to others on the site who use and are otherwise interested in leather saddles.

Comment: @zenbike I disagree; I think answers to this question would be useful to many cyclists who use Brooks saddles. I'm voting to repoen, but would be happy to discuss.

Comment: This seems to me to fall under the umbrella of "product, service, or **learning material** recommendations," which are off-topic. I'm willing to entertain thoughts to the contrary though.

Comment: @NeilFein The question is asking for a database of pressure mapping info on one particular brand of saddle. I agree that the end result of the research he proposes would be useful. I do not agree that the source for the database is useful to anyone not conducting that research.

Comment: @Rider_X The OP did not ask a question about saddles or bike fit. He asked a question about a source of information for a research project.  I did my best to supply that info, but I don't think that the question itself is relevant here.

Comment: @jimirings That was my interpretation as well.  I have nothing against the OP, and attempted to answer his question, but I don't think it will be useful to anyone else in future, which is my key metric as to its utility.

Comment: For what it's worth, the GebioMized system is awesome. Michael Fuhrmeister at GebioMized has been very helpful with everything we have needed related to the pressure mapping software and the scanner. I think he would be happy to help with this, assuming the data isn't proprietary.

Comment: @zenbike If this were some oddball brand of saddle I'd agree with you. But Brooks saddles are incredibly common. Respectfully, I think this would be generally useful. (Whether the question would be answered is another question.)

Comment: @NeilFein The question asked is does anyone have a database of pressure data regarding a particular brand of saddle. GebioMized pressure data is specific to the type of saddle, and the rider sitting on it.  It is good for 2 things: Making modifications to saddle choice or position for a particular rider, or designing a new saddle, using a wide range of pressure readings on a particular saddle to design a new saddle or chamois. Unless someone intends to do one of those things, the data is useless.

Comment: If it was useful for me to have someone else's saddle scan in relation to my fit, then I could see the utility for general use. Since it isn't useful for fitting, unless I have my own scan done, then at best this is requesting "product, service, or learning material recommendations", and off topic.  That said, if you all think it useful, feel free to vote to re-open.

Comment: @zenbike I think you are over emphasizing the specificity. It is useful to show what can be accomplished with leather saddles in terms of fit, especially compared to  modern alternatives.  This is what I aim to publish and was looking to see if it has been done before.  I can remove references to Brooks and GeioMized if that helps.

Comment: It doesn't. Regardless of the brand you are asking about, pressure data like this is only good for one thing. The thing that makes this not useful to others is that you are asking for a data source for research. Anyone not doing your research, doesn't need that. I appreciate that you want to learn, and tried to point you in the direction of someone that might have the answer you want, because I'd like to be helpful. But the question and its only possible answer are not on topic here, in my opinion. Any further discussion should be taken to meta.

Comment: @zenbike - I didn't appreciate that it was rider-specific; I see your point now. Perhaps there's a way to edit so it's useful to OP but less specific?

Comment: @NeilFein a single pressure profile taken out of context is useless,  but a series of profiles can be very informative even though a single profile is rider and position specific.

Comment: @Rider_X Only for manufacturing purposes.  For fitting purposes, not useful except in the context of a specific rider.